# Breaking down of fully faithfulness when taking its derived functor?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, derived-functors

Suppose $F$ is a fully faithful functor from abelian category $A$ to abelian category $B$, then $F$ induces a derived functor $DF$ between their derived categories,
\begin{equation}
DF:D^*A \rightarrow D^* B
\end{equation}
where $*$ could be -, +, b, $\emptyset$. When is $DF$ also fully faithful and when it is not fully faithful?